# Formula Field Case Statement checking to see if a value is between two numbers

Tags: formula-field

I am attempting to write a formula using a case statement that evaluates a field to determine a "level". For example if Total_Donations__c is between 1000.00 and 4999.99 then the result will equal "Level 1".  There are 5 levels total.  I have tried to put the following together but I am doing it incorrectly and have not been able to figure out how to piece it together.

```
Case (
    Total_Donations__c,
    (AND(Total_Donations__c > 1000.00, Total_Donations__c < 4999.99), 'Level 1',
        (AND(Total_Donations__c > 5000.00, Total_Donations__c < 9999.99), 'Level 2',
            (AND(Total_Donations__c > 10000.00, Total_Donations__c < 24999.99), 'Level 3',
                (AND(Total_Donations__c > 25000.00, Total_Donations__c < 49999.99), 'Level 4',
                    Total_Donations__c > 50000.00, 'Level 5',
                    ""
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CASE()` is not well-suited to this type of work (sorting a single number into one of a number of buckets). The function just can't work with booleans in the way we would need here.

[The documentation on the CASE() function](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_case.htm&type=5) suggests using `IF()` to return numbers instead, but at that point you're pretty much using `IF()` to do the real work instead. It starts to make sense to cut out the middleman.

The good news is that what you've shared with us is at least 80% of the way to just using nested `IF()` instead.

The other issue you have here is a hole in donation amount ranges.
When you check `Total_Donations__c < 4999.99` and `Total_Donations__c > 5000.00`, you're missing the scenario where the total donations are *exactly 5000.00*. The way math/logic works, the opposite of `<` is `>=` (not `>`).

One other thing to note is that if you fail the check for `Total_Donations__c < 4999.99`, you can assume that it is greater than or equal to 5000.00. There is no need to explicitly check that.

So putting that all together, you'd end up with

```
/* IF() always takes 3 arguments */
/* the condition, the value when the condition is true, the value when the condition is false */
/* By chaining additional IF(), we can make an if-else if-else */
IF(
    AND(Total_Donations__c > 1000.00, Total_Donations__c < 5000.00),
    "Level 1",
    IF(
        Total_Donations__c < 10000.00,
        "Level 2",
        IF(
            Total_Donations__c < 25000.00,
            "Level 3",
            /* and so on */
        )
    )
)
```

Do keep in mind that donation totals less than 1000 would also fail all of the `IF()` conditions and end up spitting out "Level 5" for you. I doubt that's what you want, so you'll need to do something to handle that scenario too.

Comment: Thank you Derek F. for the detailed answer.  That is exactly what I needed.  CASE didn't feel right but I couldn't fill in the gaps.  Thank you for the education!

Comment: The one big benefit of the case statement is built-in readability. The nested if structure can be hard to read/maintain beyond a few ifs IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Your Case statement should start with `1` (NOT TRUE/FALSE), not `Total_Donations__c`. You're evaluating the following boolean checks against that value. It also doesn't look like you have a default value which needs to follow 'Level 5'.

I'd recommend formatting your formulas with a new line for each new value for readability.

```
Case(1,
  IF(AND(...asdf), 1, 0), 'Level 1',
  IF(AND(...fdsa), 1, 0), 'Level 2',
  ...,
  'Default'
)
```

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_case.htm&type=5

Comment: Well, yes and no. That documentation that you link specifically says you can't use true/false in `CASE()` like this. `CASE functions can’t contain functions that return true or false. Instead, make true or false expressions return numbers...`

Comment: Good call, forgot about that. will update