# Row level formula: Pull value between two dates

Tags: date, if, report-formula

I am trying to make a row level formula to identify dates that are in Q1 (Sep, Oct, Nov) of two years of fiscal data. I am able to distinguish between FY23 and FY24 using

`IF(Case.End_Date__c > DATE(2023,8,31), "FY24", "FY23")`

but would like to only have the first three months of each year. I have tried the code below going off of some code I found [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/398313/formula-field-case-statement-checking-to-see-if-a-value-is-between-two-numbers), but it has not worked. I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do this and could use some help. Thanks!

```
IF(
    AND(Case.End_Date__c > DATE(2022,8,31), Case.End_Date__c < DATE(2022,12,1)), "FY 23",

   IF(
       AND(Case.End_Date__c > DATE(2023,8,31), Case.End_Date__c < DATE(2023,12,1)), "FY 24",
))
```

Comment: Take a look at https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.filter_dates_relative.htm&type=5 and https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.setting_the_fiscal_year.htm&type=5